# How to specify alpha channel selection inside SLD raster style on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is there a way to specify alpha channel inside raster SLD in GeoServer.
For example, I have a multispectral map with 6 bands(B-G-R-RE-NIR-Alpha), where the sixth band is alpha, and I would like to show it as RGBA using SLD style.
I can order channels in the ChannelSelection tag to show RGB without the Alpha channel, but how can I add an alpha channel here?

```
<ChannelSelection>
  <RedChannel>
    <SourceChannelName>3</SourceChannelName>
  </RedChannel>
  <GreenChannel>
    <SourceChannelName>2</SourceChannelName>
  </GreenChannel>
  <BlueChannel>
    <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName>
  </BlueChannel>
</ChannelSelection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLD provides no way to select an alpha channel. It could be implemented as a vendor extension, if you are interested in developing or sponsoring it, get in touch with the [GeoServer developers](http://geoserver.org/devel/)  or the [commercial support providers](http://geoserver.org/support/)